# Accessing appsettings.json (in WepApi-project) in Class library project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I know this issue has been responded to before, but I cannot seem to get it to work in my case. The solution in Visual Studio contains several project, including WepApi-project (asp.net core), and a class library project. In the class library project I need to access some info in the appsettings.json, residing in the WebApi-project. I've tried to followed different tutorials, which has lead to the following so far:

**Appsettings.json**

```
{
   "LoginSettings": {
   "email": "test@test.com",
   "password": "12345678"
   } 
}
```

Class modeling configuration (resides in class library project):

**LoginSettings**

```
public class LoginSettings
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs (WebApi-project):**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

     var loginSettings = new LoginSettings
     {
         Email = Configuration["LoginSettings:email"],
         Password = Configuration["LoginSettings:password"]
     };

     services.AddSingleton(loginSettings);
     services.AddOptions();
}
```

**Class in which I need the settings**

```
public static class Test
{
   private readonly LoginSettings settings;

   public static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
   {
       var email = settings.Email;

       ...
   }

}
```

I cannot get anything from LoginSettings. In addition, I have tried to make Test-class non-static in order to inject LoginSettings into the constructor. But when I then try to instantiate Test-class, it asks for an instance of LoginSettings. I don't really feel for making Test-class non-static, as it's only purpose is to return a string to another class, and it needs the LoginSettings to do so. What do I do wrong?

Regards.

**EDIT**

I have made the class Test non-static. What do I pass in when instatiating it?

Comment: If your Test class is non-static you should be able to do the following: Have a private class-level variable (like you do, but alter the name slightly) `private readonly LoginSettings _settings;`, and inject the class through your constructor like so: `public Test(LoginSettings settings) { _settings = settings; }`. You should now be able to use _settings within the Test class.

Comment: But I still need to inject a LoginSetting, when I instantiate the Test-class?

Comment: Well because you injected LoginSettings with this line `services.AddSingleton(loginSettings);` it should be accessible application-wide. You should still be able to do this: `var email = _settings.Email;` and then use `Test.GetTokenAsync();` without having to instantiate Test. Give it a try and see if it works, I'm just spit balling at this point.

Comment: @ChristopherLake, I got it working by injecting the LoginSettings into the Test-class, and injecting the Test-class into the class using it. I guess I still need a lot of studying before I get a grasp on all this. But thank you for your help.

Comment: None of us will ever stop learning in this profession - one of the perks if you ask me. Glad I could be of some assistance :)

Comment: I really try to understand the whole thing with ASP.NET core, class libraries, how classes are injected, etc., but with time comes experience and knowledge ^_^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<LoginSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("LoginSettings"));
}
```

In the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private string _email { get; set; }
    private string _password { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IOptions<LoginSettings> options)
    {
        var login = options.Value;
        _email = login.Email;
        _password = login.Password;
    }

    public IActionResult GetTokenAsync()
    {
        // _email: "test@test.com"
        // _password: "12345678"
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I suggest you name the property name in the `appsettings.json` like this:

```
{
   "LoginSettings": {
       "Email": "test@test.com",
       "Password": "12345678"
   } 
}
```

Use `Email` and `Password` instead of `email` and `password`.

**UPDATE** (for `I'm not going to use the LoginSettings in a controller. I'm going to use it in a class in the class library project`):

```
public class MyLib
{
    private string _email { get; set; }
    private string _password { get; set; }

    public MyLib(IOptions<LoginSettings> options)
    {
        var login = options.Value;
        _email = login.Email;
        _password = login.Password;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        // _email: "test@test.com"
        // _password: "12345678"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

To use this library. You **cannot** use it like this:

```
var lib = new MyLib(???)
```

Since `MyLib` (or `Test` in your example) is a service, you pass it in another constructor before using:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private MyLib _lib { get; set; }

    public AnotherClass(MyLib lib)
    {
        _lib = lib;
    }

    public async Task UseIt()
    {
        var token = await _lib.GetTokenAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to use the LoginSettings in a controller. I'm going to use it in a class in the class library project.

Comment: @Frederik It was same. Check the update in my answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the class as static? So I would call something like Test.GetTokenAsync? GetTokenAsync would then inside the method take care of getting the values from appsettings. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Both of the answers have a same idea: register a new service and pass it via the constructor. Since you need a static class. It should NOT work. You cannot call a service using static class.

Comment: Oka, I have modified into a non-static now. However, when I try to instantiate (taking your example with MyLib), it's asking for the argument IOptions, e.g.: `var lib = new MyLib(???)`. What do I pass in?

Comment: To use IOptions, I suggest use create a library that using .Net standard. I've made a screenshot here: https://image.ibb.co/cRp08V/Untitled.png

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now by injecting the class into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm trying to explain how it works in my case.

In my **ClassLibrary** I have the following extension method

```
public static class MyClassLibraryExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyClassLibrary(this IServiceCollection services, LoginSettings options)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<LoginSettings>(options);
        return services;
    }
}
```

then in **Web.API** project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    var loginSettings = new LoginSettings
    {
        Email = Configuration["LoginSettings:email"],
        Password = Configuration["LoginSettings:password"]
    };

    services.AddMyClassLibrary(loginSettings);
    ...
}
```

and use it

```
public class Test
{
   private readonly LoginSettings _settings;

   public Test(LoginSettings loginSettings)
   {
        _settings = loginSettings;
   }

   public static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
   {
       var email = _settings.Email;

       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot declare instance members in a static class.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Do you need static class?

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, thanks, fixed. Also there are `...` what makes the code not working. It just for example and I think does not deserve downvote.So it is definitely not compiling because `...` also as the code from question

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, I added the `...` for simulating more code to expect (not in the example though).

Comment: @Frederik Yes, I know and it is ok. It was the answer on CodeCaster comment

Comment: If OP needs a static class, your solution won't work. Same to me :)